# Comparing Odds ratios between dependant samples?

Tags: logistic, epidemiology, odds-ratio, poisson-regression

I am in a bit of quandary with a research project:

I have to compare and contrast the epidemiological picture of homicide with the media coverage of homicide in a specific geographic area and time-span. Now I'm using Poisson regression to work out the OR of a crime being committed (male vs.female, black vs white etc.) in the epidemiological data. Then I am also working out the OR for a crime story being reported based on victim characteristics (male vs. female, black vs white etc.)

Now let's say I arrive at the following: the OR for victimhood is 4.0 for male [ref group] vs female in the epidemiological data, but OR for the media covering such a homicide is 7.0 for male vs female.

Given that the samples are dependant, such that theoretically the media data is derived from/overlaps with the epidemiological data, how can I statistically compare these odds ratios?

Thanks.

Comment: Are these really dependent , ie. a crime is known to have occurred but not reported .... or do you have two separate database from which "parallel" models are being developed? If really dependent why not a hurdle model?

Comment: Hi -I forgot to mention that the specific type of crime I am looking at is Homicide - and since the epidemiological profile was established from mortuary-level data, it guarantees that the homicide occurred in a manner established by the coroner (i.e. "dead bodies don't lie").

So the samples really are dependent